# How do I fire click event if element in array is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of DOM elements. If the fourth one is clicked I want to hide the search box. If any of the other ones are clicked I want to show it. How would I do this? I currently have:

```
var app = {
    config: {
        tabs: [$("#tab1"), $("#tab2"), $("#tab3"), $("#tab4")],
        search: $("#search")
    },
    showHideSearch: function () {
        // Here I need to test if the fourth tab was clicked on then hide(); 
        // else if tabs one through three were clicked show
    }
}
app.showHideSearch();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(app.config.tabs, function(i, v) { 
  v.bind('click', function(){
    $('#searchbox').show();
    if(i==3)
      $('#searchbox').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: show() and hide() are preferred instead of setting the display via css()

Comment: the first time i looked at this it said 1==3 then i clicked to edit and it said i == 3, it doesn't say it was edited.  i think i'm going crazy

Comment: and I think your if check is messed up  if(1==3) is never true. I think you want i

Comment: you are going crazy... 1 never equals 3 :)

Comment: @dstarh You AREN'T going crazy it said 1==3 I saw it too.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about :)

Comment: @kasdega, thanks :)

fyi the best database independent way to see all the columns on a table if you don't have access to the schema is select * from TABLE where 1=3

Comment: $.each was totally what I was looking for. I couldn't remember. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an array to do this.

```
$( "#tab4" ).click( function() {
    app.config.search.hide();
    // $( "#search" ).hide();
});
$( "#tab1, #tab2, #tab3" ).click( function() {
    app.config.search.show();
    // $( "#search" ).show();
});
```

Comment: +1 Also, @JesseAtkinson additionally, you might want to consider applying a class to the elements that should show or hide. Then you can change the selector to the class names.